# Count how many 1 there are in the odd positions of an array of 32-bit numbers

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, x86

I'm implementing a simple assembly function called through a program in c, to count how many 1 there are in the odd position of an array in 32 bits. The first argument passed to the function is the pointer to the array while the second the number of elements. I do not understand what it does go to infinite loop.

// Assembly code

```
.globl ones_in_odds
.type ones_in_odds,@function

ones_in_odds:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp

movl 8(%ebp),%ecx
movl 12(%ebp),%esi

#xorl %edi,%edi
xorl %eax,%eax
subl $-1,%esi

startloop:
cmpl $0,%esi
jl endloop
movl (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx
xorl %edi,%edi

innerloop:
cmpl $16,%edi
jg startloop
shrl %edx
shrl %edx
adcl $00,%eax
incl %edi
jmp innerloop

decl %esi
jmp startloop

endloop:
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

// C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 5

int ones_in_odds(int *,size_t);

int main(){

int array[DIM] = {1,3,4,5,6};
int one = ones_in_odds(array,DIM);
printf("Il numero di 1 nelle posizioni dispari e' %d\n",one);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `decl %esi` is never reached. Learn to use a debugger, and comment your code. PS: `esi` is a callee-saved register.

Comment: thank's, how can i use a debugger for assembly? 
It is not a good thing to use the esi register? 
my book, "programming ground up", does not say anything about it.

Comment: You use the debugger the same as for C. Step the code line by line, examine variables (registers). You can use `esi` but you must preserve it for your caller according to standard calling convention (important if your code gets called from C, as seems to be the case here).

Comment: all clear, how can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **adds** 1 to `ESI`:

```
subl $-1,%esi
```

It's like the term `ESI = ESI - (-1)`. You want to transform the *count* of items (`DIM`) to the *index* of the last item in `array`. Thus the count has to be subtracted by 1 or added by (-1). However, you don't need this transformation at this place. Remove the line.

Because of

```
jg startloop
```

you don't reach `decl %esi` and therefore the break condition `jl endloop` will never been met.

Move `decl %esi` to the beginning of `startloop` and you solve also the transformation problem above.

As @Jester mentions, you have to follow the [C calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) since the assembly procedure is a function of the C program. The function is allowed to change `EAX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` ("caller saved") and has to return all other registers unchanged ("callee saved"). The function changes `ESI` and `EDI`, but should returm them unchanged. So push them at the beginning of the function and pop them at the end.