# Sum array of float in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, simd

I'm implementing a function in assembly x86, called from a C program, to add an array of float. The first argument of the function is the pointer to the array and the second is the number of elements. When I run the code in linux, I get a segmentation fault. What did I do wrong?

```
.text
.globl floatsum

floatsum:
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

movl  8(%ebp), %eax
movl 12(%ebp), %edx
shrl $2, %edx

xorps %xmm0, %xmm0
loop:
testl %edx, %edx
je end  
movaps (%eax), %xmm1
addps %xmm1, %xmm0
addl $16, %eax
decl %edx
jmp loop 

end:
                            #         3       2      1       0
movaps %xmm0, %xmm1         # xmm0:   w       z      y       x 
                            # xmm1:   z       w      x       y
shufps $0xb1, %xmm1, %xmm1  #        10      11      00      01  = 0xb1
addps  %xmm1, %xmm0         # xmm0:  w+z     z+w     y+x     x+y
movaps %xmm0, %xmm1         # xmm1:  w+z     z+w     y+x     x+y
                            # xmm1:  x+y     y+x     z+w     w+z
shufps $0x1b, %xmm1, %xmm1  #        00      01      10      11  = 0x1b
addps  %xmm1, %xmm0         # xmm0:  w+z+x+y z+w+y+x y+x+z+w x+y+w+z
                            #
#movd %xmm0, %eax
#pushl %eax

finst:

flds (%esp)
popl %eax

movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

// C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float
floatsum(float *array, size_t number_of_items);

float
floatsum_c(float *array, size_t number_of_items){
float sum;
size_t i;

sum=0.0;
for(i=0; i<number_of_items;i++){
    sum+=array[i];
}
return sum;
}

float *
create_array(size_t number_of_items){
float *array;
size_t i;

array=calloc(number_of_items, sizeof(float));
if(array){
    for(i=0; i<number_of_items; i++){
        array[i]=1.0+(float)i;
    }
   }
   return array;
 }

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
float *a;
float result;
size_t number_of_items, i;

number_of_items=8;
a=create_array(number_of_items);
if(a){
    result=floatsum_c(a, number_of_items);
    printf("Sum (c version): %f\n", result);    
    result=floatsum(a, number_of_items);
    printf("Sum (asm version): %f\n", result);  
    free(a);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Where does the crash occur ? I'm guessing at `movaps (%eax), %xmm1` ? If so then it's probably an alignment problem.

Comment: yes, the problem is causeb by movaps (%eax), %xmm1, how can i solve it? @PaulR

Comment: Can you show the _C_ code you use to call this?

Comment: As I said above, it's probably an alignment problem - you can check the address in your debugger to see whether it's 16-byte aligned, or you can just change `movaps` to `movups` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I add C code @MichaelPetch.

Comment: movups don't work, - nan error @PaulR

Comment: You sure you assembled your code after making the change  for `movups`?

Comment: If it's not an alignment problem then it may just be an invalid address - you really are going to have to [learn how to use your debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43306288/253056)... (and providing a [mcve] might be a good idea too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Paul mentioned this is likely an alignment issue. It is clear from your *C* code that your float array is not guaranteed to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary. The failure is this line:

```
movaps (%eax), %xmm1
```

The reason is that [*MOVAPS*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVAPS.html) has this requirement:

> When the source or destination operand is a memory operand, the operand must be aligned on a **16-byte (128-bit version)** or 32-byte (VEX.256 encoded version) boundary or a general-protection exception (#GP) will be generated.

Since you are working with 128-bit vector registers you need 16-byte alignment. You have two choices:

- Change *MOVAPS* to [*MOVUPS*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVUPS.html) so that unaligned memory access can be done
- Modify your *C* code to create an array of floats aligned on a 16-byte boundary

---

First solution would require:

```
movaps (%eax), %xmm1
```

to be changed to;

```
movups (%eax), %xmm1
```

The second solution is to avoid using [*calloc*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) and utilize a function that allows you to create objects with 16-byte alignment. If using *C11* then you can use the function [*aligned_alloc*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) and [*memset*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to zero the array. Your `create_array` could look like:

```
float *
create_array(size_t number_of_items)
{
    float *array = NULL;
    size_t i;

    array=(float *)aligned_alloc(16, number_of_items * sizeof(*array));
    if(array){
        memset (array, 0x00, number_of_items * sizeof(*array));
        for(i=0; i<number_of_items; i++){
            array[i]=1.0+(float)i;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

If you are not using C11 you can utilize the POSIX function [*posix_memalign*](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign) and *memset* on Linux. The code could look something like:

```
float *
create_array(size_t number_of_items)
{
    float *array = NULL;
    size_t i;

    if (!posix_memalign((void **)&array, 16, number_of_items * sizeof(*array))){
        memset (array, 0x00, number_of_items * sizeof(*array));
        for(i=0; i<number_of_items; i++){
            array[i]=1.0+(float)i;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

You will have to uncomment these lines as well:

```
#movd %xmm0, %eax
#pushl %eax
```

so that they appear this way:

```
movd %xmm0, %eax
pushl %eax
```

---

**Note**: Although I use *memset* to zero out the float array like *calloc* would have, it isn't actually needed in your code since you initialize all the elements to specific values afterwards. In your case the call to *memset* can be removed.